# Automatically fill a cell's verification list with existing formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I have a lot of items to add into a list. They are things like "0 - Testing", "1 - Verification", "10 - Lessons", etc.

I have all of these items arranged in cells and named out with proper formatting I'd like to use.

However, I have not found a way to both make a Verification List *and* have it automatically take the formatting already in the cells it's making the list from. I've only seen ways to first create the list, and *then* format separately, one by one. That's frustrating and going to be a ton of manual work.

Is there a way for a verification list to automatically take the formatting of the list's cells?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be in need of conditional formatting. Go to the menu *Format > Conditional formatting...* and then define your formats depending on what you expect in the cells. Example below:

[image]

Comment: Maybe, but it could help if no better answer is offered.